# Trabalhar com dois Datasets diferentes - Filtrar o dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, pandas

Dataset - Players
[image: Dataset - Players]

Dataset - Results
[image: Dataset - Results]

Boa noite,

Estou empacado em uma limpeza de dados.
Estou trabalhando em um projeto para prever os vencedores de uma determinada partida de Counter Strike Global Offensive, para meu projeto de final de curso.

Porém as bases de dados possuem dados que não convergem.
No dataset players possui valores na coluna "match_id" que não estão presentes na coluna "match_id" do dataset results e vice e versa

**Tenho dificuldade em manipulação dos dados:
Como faço para que ambos os datasets possuam o mesmo "match_id"? Pois existem "match_id" divergentes em ambas os datasets**

P.S retirei os datasets desse tópico no kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/mateusdmachado/cs-go-professional-matches-analysis

P.S 2 - Eu tentei a seguinte solução sem resultado, fora as outras que deram errado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se pode usar o método isin do pandas para filtrar os dados que estão numa coluna usando uma série ou array ([documentação aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)).

Por exemplo, para pegar todos os jogos no dataframe `loc_results` que aparecem no  `loc_players` é só filtrar o dataframe usando `loc_results["match_id"].isin(loc_players["match_id"])`. Depois é só usar essa série para filtrar o dataframe.

```
filter = loc_results["match_id"].isin(loc_players["match_id"])
loc_results_filtered = loc_results[filter]
```

Comment: Obrigado @renatomt,  `matches_results = pd.DataFrame()`  `for i in range (0, loc_results.shape[0]):`  `if results[["match_id"]].isin(players[["match_id"]])==True` 
 `matches_results = results.append(results.iloc[[i]])`  
  

 **Acredito que você me aproximou mais do ponto que eu quero chegar, mas ao realizar esse procedimento apareceu um outro erro:  
 "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."**

Comment: Para filtrar o dataframe se não precisa fazer um for loop. Supondo que vc tem uma série de verdadeiro e falso chamada `serie_bool` se pode usar `df[serie_bool]` e ele te retorna df com apenas os elementos que são verdadeiros na `serie_bool`

Comment: Para a forma que você me passou, a resposta foi a comparação dos dataframe que retornaram True or False.  **Eu preciso remover os itens divergentes de ambos os dataframes**.   Por isso usei essa condição de for loop, que provavelmente está errada.

Comment: ```
filter = df["series"].isin(df2["series"])
df3 = df[filter]
```
df3 nesse caso vai ser o df filtrado onde a coluna series tem o mesmo valor em df e df2. Se precisa fazer isso prós dois dataframes e se consegue os dataframes só com as partidas que tem nos dois.

Comment: filter = players["match_id"].isin(results["match_id"])  
matches_players = pd.DataFrame()  
matches_players = players[filter]  
matches_players  

MUITO OBRIGADO! DEU CERTO!